# How to write text containing multiple languages in a PDF document using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I guess it's all in the title, is it possible ? i tried using fonts but the problem is that a font that works for chinese for instance would'nt work for arabic and so on.

Comment: Can you use multiple fonts? I've never used TCPDF (I use FPDF instead), but it ought to be possible to use one font for Chinese and another for Arabic.

Comment: @Kryten actually it did work, just setting the font again and writing the text did the trick, you can add an answer and i'll gladly accept it

Comment: Partial answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426983/creating-pdfs-using-tcpdf-that-supports-all-languages-especially-cjk